# Numpy vectorization error

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following equation.  I have it working in non-vectorized form

[image: Variances]

```
print(K)
print(N)
print(gamma.shape)
print(means.shape)
print(img.shape)
print(N_k.shape)
```

yields

```
2
1000
(1000, 2)
(2,)
(1000)
(2,)



self.variances = np.sum(gamma * (img  - self.means) ** 2) / N_k
```

This gives me the wrong answer.  The answer has the correct shape but the values are way off

However

```
self.variances = [ np.sum([gamma[n][k] * (img[n] - self.means[k]) ** 2 for n in range(0, N)]) / N_k[k] for k in range(0, K) ]
```

works.  I'm new to numpy so I'm sure I've made a stupid mistake but I'm unable to find it in this case

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
self.variances = np.sum(gamma * (img[:, None] - self.means) ** 2, axis=0) / N_k
```

instead of

```
self.variances = np.sum(gamma * (img - self.means) ** 2) / N_k
```

---

```
import numpy as np

N, K = 10, 20
gamma = np.random.random((N, K))
means = np.random.random(K)
N_k = np.random.random(K)
img = np.random.random(N)

expected = np.array([ np.sum([gamma[n][k] * (img[n] - means[k]) ** 2 for n in range(0, N)]) / N_k[k] for k in range(0, K) ])

result = np.sum(gamma * (img[:, None]  - means) ** 2, axis=0) / N_k

assert np.allclose(result, expected)
```

---

Note that `img - self.means` subtracts corresponding values *elementwise*.
`img` has shape `(N,)` and `self.means` has shape `(K,)`, so subtracting one from the other is possible if `N == K`, but raises an ValueError if `N != K` since then the shapes are incompatible. Since you didn't get an error, `N` must be equal to `K`.

Since you want to compute a 2D array of values, first make `img` a 2D array of shape `(N, 1)` by adding a new axis: `img[:, None]`.

Then take advantage of
[broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) so
that when you subtract the 1D array `self.means`, it will broadcast to a 2D
array of compatible shape `(N, K)`. Broadcasting by default adds new axes *on
the left*. Thus the array of shape `(K,)` can automatically broadcast to an
array of shape `(N, K)`. (This also explains why we needed to use `img[:, None]` to explicitly add a new axis on the right.)

Now `(img[:, None] - self.means)` will be a 2D array of shape `(N, K)`.

---

Also note that it is important to specify `axis=0` when calling `np.sum` because the summation is done over the first axis of length `N`. Since Python uses 0-based indexing the first axis corresponds to `axis=0`.

If you don't specify an axis, then `np.sum` sums over all axes by default.

Comment: Or with `np.einsum` : `diffs = img[:,None] - self_means ; out = np.einsum('ij,ij,ij->j',gamma,diffs,diffs)/N_k`. Could be faster.

Comment: Well it turns out that img is actually (N, 1) in shape.  This code was enough to get me in the right direction.  Thanks